# Magento: Product quantity import with multiple stock_id for every product_id

Tags: php, arrays, magento, magento-1.7

I have a module which allows for multiple warehouse locations and this uses the stock_id field in the catalognventory_stock_item table.

For a scenario where there are 2 products, and 4 warehouses; and each warehouse got 8 units of product 1 and 4 units of product 2; the cataloginventory_stock_item table looks like this.

```
item_id | product_id | stock_id | qty
   1    |     1      |     1    |  8
   2    |     1      |     2    |  8
   3    |     1      |     3    |  8
   4    |     1      |     4    |  8
   5    |     2      |     1    |  4
   6    |     2      |     2    |  4
   7    |     2      |     3    |  4
   8    |     2      |     4    |  4
```

Essentially:
 
item_id = id
product_id = the product identifier
stock_id = the warehouse identifier

Now, I currently programatically import products using a script like this (cut down version)

```
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->setSku('importproduct1');
    $product->setName('Import Product 1');
    $product->setTypeId('simple');
    ...
    $product->setStockData(array(
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 5
    ));
    $product->save();
```

I am struggling to find how to use the setStockData method to apply quantities in the required arrangement.

I have tried

```
$product->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 5
    'stock_id' =>1
));
```

I think it need to use multiple arrays for each stock_id but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: What happens when you run the last bit of code you posted? Does anything get saved in the DB?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was incorrect. With the code above on a CLEAN installation without the multi-warehouse module. (But with a stock ID other than 1) it just saves the import with stock id 1. 
On an install with the multi-warehouse module nothing is saved.

Comment: It depends on how the module you have installed deals with multiple stock per product. Does it just modify the curreny stock db table etc

Comment: Hi Andrew, it uses the same cataloginventory_stock_item table that is default in Magento. It also uses the same column by default which is stock_id. I'm just unable to programatically set a stock id in my script.

Comment: Checkout Xtento stockimport that support multiple stock_Id

Comment: A question to you: what extension are you using? Sounds like something that we need. Really appreciate your reply.